# Google Sheet: How to implode a range resulted from a query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Teacher sheet and a Class sheet, each class is associated with a teacher, and a teach may teach more than one class. In the Teacher sheet, I want a column to show what classes a teacher teaches，the classes being separated by `,`.

Using `Query` function, I have been able to retrieve a single column range of the classes a particular teacher is teaching

```
QUERY('Class'!A:I,"select B where G='John Smith'")  
//The Class sheet's rightmost column is `I`, column B is `Class_Name` and column G is `Class_Teacher`.
```

However, I can't find a fomula to "implode" this result with `,`, the closes I was able to find is `concatenate`

```
concatenate(QUERY('Class'!A:I,"select B where G='John Smith'"))
```

This will output all the classes John Smith is teaching without `,`. Can this be done with fomula or I will have to write a custom fomula in app script?

Comment: look at [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) or [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the JOIN() function.

```
=JOIN(",", QUERY('Class'!A:I,"select B where G='John Smith'")))
```